# Stuck on relative angular motion and inertial forces

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, centrifugal-force

OK,before I start explaining my problem, let's consider this system - You have a particle rotating about the z-axis of an inertial frame of reference, with angular velocity $\omega$ with a radius $r$, let's label all the quantities measured with respect to this frame of reference with a subscript $A$. Now let's consider frame of reference $B$, which is rotating about it's z axis with angular velocity $\omega _0$, and the z-axis coincides with that of $A$.

If I were to find out the net acceleration of the particle in $B$, it obviously will be $\omega _B ^2 \cdot r$
And $\omega _B = \omega _A - \omega _0 = \omega - \omega _0$
So, I could say that the net acceleration is $\left( \omega - \omega _0 \right)^2\cdot r$
But if I were to approach it using inertial forces,
$$ma = -F_B + F_A$$
$F_B$ is the centrifugal force caused by the rotation of B
$$F_B = m\cdot w_0^2r, \space F_A = m\cdot w_a^2r$$
$$\therefore a = r\cdot \left[ w^2 - w_0^2 \right]$$
[image: Diagram with respect to RoF A]
[image]

So, yeah, what am I doing wrong? I can't get my head around this concept..

EDIT: Made a few mistakes in the last two equations

Comment: @user163104 Yeah, I still don't get it

Comment: @user163104 Was that for you guys on the site? OK, I misunderstood that.. I'll add one shortly

Comment: @user163104 I've added diagrams now, please have a look at it

Comment: @user163104 I usually do that. Thank you for your help :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centrifugal force $F_0=mr\omega_0^2$ is not the only fictitious force in a rotating frame of reference. When the object is moving with non-zero velocity $v$ in the rotating frame, there is also a [**Coriolis force**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#Formula), which has magnitude $F_1=2m\omega_0 v$. This force is what you are missing.

In your example, $v=r(\omega-\omega_0)$, so the Coriolis force is
$F_1=2mr\omega_0(\omega-\omega_0)=2mr(\omega_0\omega-\omega_0^2)$.

If $\omega>\omega_0$ as in your example - ie the object is moving in the direction of rotation - then the Coriolis force is outward, away from the axis, the same as the centrifugal force. If $\omega<\omega_0$ the Coriolis force would be inward, towards the axis.

The centripetal force measured in the rotating frame of reference is therefore
$F_B=F_A-F_0-F_1$
$=mr\omega^2-mr\omega_0^2-2mr(\omega_0\omega-\omega_0^2)$
$=mr(\omega^2-2\omega_0\omega_0+\omega_0^2)$
$=mr(\omega-\omega_0)^2$
which agrees with your formula for the *net acceleration* $r(\omega-\omega_0)^2$ measured in B's frame of reference.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's Second Law only holds in inertial reference frames.

If $A$ is an inertial frame, then $F_A=ma_A$.  Since the $B$ reference frame is rotating with respect to the $A$ frame, $B$ is a non-inertial frame; thus $F_B\ne m a_B$ for the quantities measured in the $B$ frame.

Comment: Sorry about this, but I actually made a few mistakes the last time I posted since I was copying from my on hand notes, and messed up the pages, it's fine now, could you have a look at it again?

Comment: The answer still holds.  You're looking at the particle's motion in two frames, at least one of which is non-inertial.  In the non-inertial frame, Newton's Second Law doesn't apply.

Comment: That's only as long as I don't include intertial forces, I've included the centrifugal force caused by the rotation of B, so Newton's second law should still apply

Comment: In a non-inertial frame Newton's Second Law doesn't apply.  Pick one of your frames to be inertial, say $A$.  Then apply $F_A = m a_A$ all in $A$.  (Note that in your question you don't specify which frame you're in when applying $ma=-F_B+F_A$.)

Comment: It certainly was in reference frame B, which is why I included the pseudo-force $F_B = w_0^2r$. Newton's second law should work just fine after adding this